# Need Example Using @wordpress/hooks In Node Program

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, hook

I'd like to add the ability to hook into a Node.js program I am writing for release. Ideally, I'd like something like the Wordpress Hook system (traditionally for PHP and recently for Javascript!) that is very robust, yet simple.

It seems WP has released a Node module for just this purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/hooks

However, I can find no documentation or real-world examples explaining how exctly to implement this.

Lets say I have a function that does this:

```
function processObj(myObj){
  doThing1(myObj);
  doThing2(myObj);
  // I want to allow plugin writers to add a Thing3, Thing4, etc...
  return myObj;
}
```

I believe this is a filter... As in I want to allow plugins to filter myObj through Thing3 (which they create) before the return. But I'm lost as to how to implement.